# Execute a program on boot in linux in terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, debian, boot

I am working on a project on a raspberry Pi Model 2+ using Raspbian Debian jessie and this is my problem :/

So i have a program (written in C++) that I launch using a shell script
(the shell script basically relaunches my program whenever it crashes, this is unsolveable since it will fail once in a while because of the hardware I am using***)

I was looking on google for answers on how to launch a program on boot and saw that i can put everything in RC.local as a script @/etc/RC.local.
So now I have this:

```
sudo /home/pi/Morreels/launcher
```

in rc.local, this launches the process since i can kill it using `killall launcher` after being logged in. 
Sadly i need this program to output to the terminal so that's where i am stuck, i've seen people launching the terminal and then echo'ing the run codes for the program inside the terminal, but isn't this a dirty fix ?

I feel like there should be some kind of option like -lx at the end of my command to make it output into the terminal, no ?

Sadly, about this i don't seem to find anything, and if I SHOULD use the above mentioned dirty fix, i would love some help since I dont seem to get that to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the output in a terminal? When the rc-scripts are run there simply is no terminal available to redirect the output into.

Maybe a logfile could help you here? Redirect the output to 
    /var/log/morreels_launcher.log
for example and then check this file instead of the terminal?

PS: The sudo should not be necessary in rc-scripts.

Comment: The output shows me whats wrong, you see when one of the connected devices fails or anything like that my program keeps trying to connect and so i need to see which device is failing so i can fix this device without having to go into the raspberry's logs to see errors.

Comment: Then maybe the redirection into a logfile `/var/log/morreels_launcher.log` and when logged in a `tail -f /var/log/morreels_launcher.log` in a new terminal could provide this.

Comment: This would mean that in my (by now) over 1200 lines-large program i would need to edit every single cout,printd,perror and so on ? including in the plugins?

Just asking ^^

Comment: No, you can redirect both stdout and stderr to a logfile with `/home/pi/Morreels/launcher > /var/log/morreels_launcher.log 2>&1`. There is no need to change your program to do this.

Comment: Great i will try this :)

Comment: Okay so this method works if I input the "Tail -f /var...." line after booting manually in a terminal, but I need it to start on boot without me typing or doing anything... 

I did see that it's possible to boot in some kind of terminal mode so maybe this would be the answer ?

Comment: Unless it's possible to launch the second line (tailing the logfile) as well, since it isn't working in RC.local I suppose not ?

Comment: As stated in another answer you will need to perform this 2nd task when logging in into you system. I don't have a raspbian system at hand right now, but maybe something like `xterm -e tail /var/log/morreels_launcher.log &` in `.xinitrc` in your home directory. Maybe have a look if `xtail` which outputs the content of the monitored file(s) onto your X screen's background, I find this quite helpful sometimes.

Comment: Then this is not an option for me since it should be full automated, not needing any input before full running and displaying all errors. 
In my software i schedule reboots, so after doing so i should be able to get back to the initial state (in terminal etc without any input) So I will keep searching for an answer :)

Comment: Maybe enabling auto login is just enough? Or is no graphical login environment installed? Then maybe replacing the `exec`-command in `/etc/init/tty1.conf` by the `tail`-command will display all messages directly? I hope this file is the same in raspbian.

Comment: I'll check for that :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help and support, it is greatly appreciated, I have configured the raspberry Pi to boot into the non-GUI (commandline) and execute the "launcher" script from there by simply putting it into the RC.Local file (even though now it's telling me error:failed) all the time, I'm sure i will be able to fix it. (otherwise keep an eye out for a subsequent question ;) ) Buuuut anyways thanks a million for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the text terminal: `launcher > /dev/console` (or `&> console` to also redirect stderr). If you mean an X11 terminal, it depends on the window manager. For gnome there is a GUI in the main menu that you can use to configure X11 startup apps.

Comment: i will try this :)

Comment: So I tried this but sadly when i enter this behind the rc.local code line, it doesn't work anymore, the process doesn't get started and no terminal

i checked by trying `killall launcher`